# Request POST in JavaScript with timeout

Tags: javascript, ajax, post, request, timeout

I would like to send a request like:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: url,
  data: data,
  success: function(data) {
    console.log(data);
    var file = new Blob([data], {
      type: 'application/zip'
    });
    var fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);
    window.open(fileURL);
  },
  error: function(xmlhttprequest, textstatus, message) {
    if (textstatus === "timeout") {
      alert("got timeout");
    } else {
      alert(textstatus);
    }
  },
  timeout: 10000
});
```

But the timeout isn't enough. I have an error in Java server:

> Try to write on a closed channel[keepAlive:true]: Remote host may have closed the connection

Is there a way to make a query that keeps the connection open until the answer?

Thanks

Comment: Probably it is a server side problem, you need to change the timeout into your server site app

Answer (score 1):

set timeout to 0 for unlimited, by default it is 0, but some browsers have their own timeouts. I hope you also are aware that timeout is in milliseconds, so you're only waiting for 10 seconds, may be try increasing it to some 60 seconds (60000), if `timeout: 0` isn't working